# How can I get this Javascript issue running as required?

Tags: javascript, function, scope, closures

I need to get the outputs from the inputs one after the other:-

1. Input: `John Lennon`
2. Output: `John Lennon`
3. Input: `John Lennon`
4. Output: `John Lennon`
5. Input again: `George Harrison`
6. Output: `John Lennon`
7. Input: `Paul McCartney`
8. Output: `Paul McCartney`
9. Input again: `John Lennon`
10. Output: `Paul McCartney`

To retest, you must refresh the browser page

```js
let rememberedMan;

const getName = (name) => {
    rememberedMan = 'John Lennon';
    
    if(name === 'John Lennon') {
        return rememberedMan;
    }

    if(name === 'George Harrison') {
        return rememberedMan;
    }

    rememberedMan = 'Paul McCartney';

    if(name === 'John Lennon') {
        return rememberedMan;
    }
    
    return name;
}
```

I want to achieve all the outputs one by one every time I enter the inputs

Comment: Which tests? What npm results? What does this have to do with scope?

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?? You could use a static local variable by adding getName.called and then if the function runs more than once output the rememberedMan. I'm trying to understand exactly what the problem is but I hope this helps.

(I forgot to add the called++ in front of name)
Edited:

```
let rememberedMan;
let called = 0;

const getName = (name) => {
getName.called;

rememberedMan = 'John Lennon';

if(name === 'John Lennon' && called == 0) {
    called++;
    return rememberedMan;
}

if(name === 'George Harrison') {
    called++;
    return rememberedMan;
}

rememberedMan = 'Paul McCartney';

if(name === 'John Lennon') {
    called++;
    return rememberedMan;
}

if(rememberedMan == 'Paul McCartney' && called >= 1) {
    return 'John Lennon';
}

called++;
return name;
}
```

Comment: It did not achieve the last requirement, which is 'when the input is 'John Lennon' it returns 'Paul McCartney'. Thanks for the try.

Comment: when the 'rememberedMan' value changed from 'John Lennon' to 'Paul McCartney' I should be able to return 'Paul McCartney' in the last condition but that did not happen!! in short, rememberedMan has to return 'John Lennon' in the first if statement, and when called again in the last statement it has to return 'Paul McCartney'.

Comment: I just edited it, let me know if that works

Comment: How so? I just tested all conditions, it works. The other thing I just fixed was the George Harrison requirement. Are there other conditions?

Answer (score 0):

if what i understood was correct , this input again is about function calling another function right ? , also the use of closure , which allows us to return argument of the first function even after it has finished execution , so you could put input then another input in the called function and expect the output they want you can also just call the second function without input because the argument has default

```
const getName = name => {
  return function (arg2 = 'John Lennon') {
    if (arg2 === 'George Harrison') return name;
    if (arg2 === 'John Lennon') return name;
    return arg2;
  };
};

console.log(getName('John Lennon')('George Harrison'));
```

anyway , this is what i was trying , could you check this and tell me if that is what you mean or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Copy and Paste this code block in your code editor then save, then test ALL the test scenarios, one after another. You have to refresh the browser page you're testing on, every time before you start a new test. Check out the image attached with the answer.

```js
let rememberedMan = 'John Lennon';

 const getName = (name) => {
    if(name === 'John Lennon') {
        return rememberedMan;
    }
    rememberedMan = 'Paul McCartney'

    if(name === 'George Harrison') {
        return 'John Lennon';
    }

    if(name === 'John Lennon') {
        return rememberedMan;
    }

    return name;
}
```

[image]